# Expression cannot contain lambda expression -Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-2015

Although, it is known that visual studio 2015 allows debugging of lambda expression and one can view it in immediate and watch window, I am still getting the error stating - Expression Cannot contain lambda expressions.

```
?lstClientDBs.Select(obj=>obj.ClientDatabase)
Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
```

**Is there any option or something, I should've turned on?** I am not able to debug or view the outcome of lambda expressions.

Comment: have you tried googling the exact error..? I found this among several when doing a `C# stackoverflow Experession cannot contain lamda expressions` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470607/expression-cannot-contain-lambda-expressions

Comment: @MethodMan - Yes. I did and none of them is solving the issue at hand. Please take a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Does a Select statement actually work like that? I'm probably just brainfarting, but wouldn't you need a comparison in that statement as well? `lstClientDBs.Select(obj=>obj.ClientDatabase == x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about new feature in `VS2015` but try setting the expression to a variable and then debug like

```
var data = lstClientDBs.Select(obj=>obj.ClientDatabase);
```

Strange but looks like MS declares that they have added that feature in `VS2015 debugger` (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015/)

Also, you probably meant to use a `Where()` extension method than `Select()` like

```
var data = lstClientDBs.Where(obj=>obj.ClientDatabase);
```