# Checking if atleasst one element in a list of a particular column has a value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a list as follows:

```
public class Emp
{
  public string? Name {get;set;}
  public int? Id {get;set;}
}
```

I have a list as:

```
List<Emp> empList = new List<Emp>();
```

The input for the list is:

```
{"A",null}
{null,null}
```

I want to check if Name in the list has value for atleast for one object.
In this case , since "A" is present I should get true.
Similarly If I ask for ID , I should get false because both are null.

I tried this:
Edit:

```
if(empList.Any(x=> x.Name != null))
```

I get an error:

> "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions"

How do I check it?

Edit:
Making the property as nullable

Comment: This code does not give that compiler error. Are you running the `Any()` in a Watch or Immediate Window?

Comment: @CodeCaster : Yes I am using using in Watch

Comment: You can't. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions) and [Expression cannot contain lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470607/expression-cannot-contain-lambda-expressions).