# Error while converting datatable to array[] using linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am trying to convert from datatable to array[] using linq and then join that array in one string using string.join.

Here is the code:

```
string.Join("','", dt
  .Select("IsCount = '1'")
  .OfType<DataRow>()
  .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>(0))
  .ToArray())
```

But it gives error like:

> Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

Comment: `.ToArray()` is *redundant* in the context, since `string.Join` accepts `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: The error you see is from the debugger. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. What NET version are you using?

Comment: Think this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470607/expression-cannot-contain-lambda-expressions

Comment: @Tim Schmelter actual error is `cannot perform '=' operation on System.Boolean and System.String`.

Comment: and i'm using .net 3.5 framework.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column IsCount?, From the error message it is a boolean and you are comparing against the string '1' Use True instead (without quotes)

Comment: Mixing `DataTable.Select` with its funky query language and `Enumerable.Select` in one expression is quite confusing. I recommend using `.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(dr => dr.Field<bool>("IsCount"))` instead.

Comment: @Steve used TRUE instead of '1' and it worked, thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you compare a `bool` column with the string `"1"`. That doesn't work in [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx). You can look how the syntax works and what it supports in [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Boolean literals are true and false; they are not quoted in
>   expressions.

So this would work:

```
string result = string.Join("','", dt
  .Select("IsCount = true")
  .Cast<DataRow>()
  .Select(dr => dr.Field<string>(0))); // no need for ToArray with NET 4
```

But instead of the strange and old `Select` syntax, why don't you use only LINQ?

```
string result = string.Join("','", dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(row => row.Field<bool>("IsCount"))
  .Select(row => row.Field<string>(0)));
```